# How Do I Build a Class with in a Class in Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to model services and I am having some issue. What I am trying to do is I would want something such as this in code:

```
>>> service = Service()
>>> service.name = "Instance1"
>>> service.name.color = "red"
>>> service.name.color.enabled = True
```

I have tried nesting the Classes but I am still having issues. 
Is this completely against convention. If so I will reevaluate and find another way to do so.

EDIT:
I decided to do something like the following by just nesting the classes to copy the Hierarchy.

```
class Service(object):
_prefix = 'Service'
def __init__(self):
    self.name = Service.Name()
class Name(object):
    _prefix = 'Service'
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = Service.Name.Color()
    class Color(object):
        _prefix = 'Service'
        def __init__(self, color="N/A"):
            self.color = color
```

Comment: What is the real-world equivalent of `service.name.color`?

Comment: "I have tried nesting the Classes but I am still having issues." What kind of issues? Perhaps composition would be a better idea than nesting.

Comment: If `service.name` is a string, then what is the expected meaning/behaviour of `<string>.color`?

Comment: Why `sevice.name.color` instead of `service.name` and `service.color`? (Okay, maybe `name` is just one attribute of a service that could be colored, but does it make sense for a *color* to be enabled, or is it the thing that is colored that is enabled?)

Comment: As mentioned, color is just a string. If all you will do with this is enable it then you could just have two attributes `color` and `colorEnabled`.

Comment: The code above is just a sample of "how would I" not this is what it will be doing. I am trying to build models of networking services, similar to YANG data models. So if I am trying to model a service such as BGP for example it would have different tiers of the configuration. I am trying to mimmic that hierarchy within python. So far composition is looking like the proper way to do so. - Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be looking at composition, not nested classes.

```
class Color:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

class Service:
     def __init__(self, color_obj):
         self.color_obj = color_obj

service = Service(Color("yellow"))
print(service.color_obj.name)
>> "yellow"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not against convention to have other objects as values of attributes of your class.

The best thing you can do it declare your desired classes - in your example these would be `class Color`, which would have a boolean attribute `enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid having nested classes, for example:

```
class Color:

    def __init__(self, name, enabled=False):
        self.name = name
        self.enabled = enabled

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Service:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.palette = None


class Palette:

    def __init__(self):
        self.colors = []

    def __str__(self):
        return ' - '.join([str(c) for c in self.colors])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_services = 8
    num_colors = 256
    offset = num_colors / num_services

    palettes = [Palette() for i in range(num_services)]
    services = [Service("Service" + str(i)) for i in range(num_services)]
    colors = [Color("color" + str(i)) for i in range(num_colors)]

    for i in range(num_services):
        subcolors = colors[i * offset:(i + 1) * offset]
        palettes[i].colors = subcolors
        services[i].palette = palettes[i]
        print "Palette {0} -> {1}\n".format(i, palettes[i])
```

Although I'm not sure what's the meaning of enabling a color in this context

Answer (score 0):

If you mean nested *instances*, you just create them in the relevant `__init__` code (or subsequently)

```
>>> class LR( object):
...   def __init__(self, L=None, R=None):
...     self.left = L
...     self.right = R

>>> class Thing(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.tree2=LR( LR(1,2), LR(3,4) )

>>> t = Thing()
>>> t.tree2.left.right
2
```

In this context, Python modules `collections.namedtuple` and `attrs` may be of use. (`attrs` is quite awesome: https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

If you mean some rather deeper magic like Django's nested `Meta` classes, then the source code is available. (It's clear enough how to use Django, but I can't say I understand the ins and outs of the nested `Meta` declaration well enough to do anything similar from scratch in my own code).

```
Class Person( models.Model)
   name = models.CharField( max_length = 100)
   ... # more field declarations
   Class Meta:
      unique_together = (("name", "birthdate"),)
      .... # more Meta-declarations
```